# Convert Decimal values(hours) to Appropriate Hours in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column called TimeSpent of type Float.

It contains values (i.e.  2.50, 1.25, 3.75, 5.60 )

I need to convert these hour values to appropriate hour values like (2:30, 1:15, 3:45 ,5:36) etc)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `Query`

```
select 
time_decimal
,cast(cast(cast(time_decimal as int) as varchar)+
':'+cast(cast((time_decimal - cast(time_decimal as int)) * 60 as int) as varchar)+
':'+cast(cast(((time_decimal - cast(time_decimal as int)) * 60-
    cast((time_decimal - cast(time_decimal as int)) * 60 as int)) * 60 as int) as varchar) as time) as real_time
from time1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55621/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created already a column with datatype time, you update your table by concatenating the left of TimeSpent till the dot and the part right of the dot multiplied by 60.

SQL Server 2012:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET
newTimeColumn = CONCAT(CAST(TimeSpentFloat AS INT), ':', (TimeSpentFloat - CAST(TimeSpentFloat AS INT)) * 60);
```

SQL Server 2008 and lower:

```
SELECT 
CAST(CAST(2.75 AS INT) AS CHAR) + ':' + CAST((2.75 - CAST(2.75 AS INT)) * 60 AS CHAR);
```

See it working in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13538/0).

Comment: Concat is not working in SQL Server 2008.Getting Error as "Concat is not a built in Function"

Answer (score 0):

Just do the math: the hour you can get by casting to int, for example. To get the minutes, multiply the decimal part by 60, etc.
A quick and dirty way to do it in a single query could be:

```
declare @d float
set @d = 1.54
select cast(@d as int) h,
       cast((@d - cast(@d as int)) * 60 as int) m,
       cast(((@d - cast(@d as int)) * 60
            - cast((@d - cast(@d as int)) * 60 as int)) * 60 as int) s
```